# Google map background ratio is not good

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation

I'm coding a website with the foundation framework, and i'm trying to put a Google Map in a large-6 columns div.

As you can see below the map ratio is not good, but the picto are OK.

[image: Google map]

I tried to play with the JS settings but nothing change...

Here is the JS:

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 5
    });

   // I populate the map with marker here, then

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for(var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++){
        bounds.extend(markerArray[i]);
   }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

I got no specific CSS for the `#map`, it used to works well with a large-12 columns div (100% wide).

Comment: I don't think JS would help in fitting the ratio into the div. Better to give 100% width and auto height.

Comment: Have you tried to set a minimum height and width: `div#map-canvas{min-height:100%;min-width:100%}`?

Comment: Check if you don't have any css styles set, which would affect all the `img`s in your `#map` div. Google maps tiles are just images so if there is some additional setting it might mess them up.

Comment: The 100% min are not working, and i got no css on `#map` at all